# Dynamic routing in cakephp while adding new products

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to do dynamic routing in my cakephp website where I have a table called products.Initially I did a static routing for each product but when new products are added,it creates a problem cause someone has to manually  enter a routing path for each new product, which doesnt seem very user friendly..Initally I did

```
Routing::connect('/portfolio/product_name1',array( 'controller'=>'products','action'=>'view',1));
Routing::connect('/portfolio/product_name2',array( 'controller'=>'products','action'=>'view',2));
Routing::connect('/portfolio/product_name3',array( 'controller'=>'products','action'=>'view',3));
```

and so on for x products.But if somebody adds another product after some time,they will have to change in the routes files too . Is there an option where I can keep it dynamic? My view() action takes id as an argument, how can i get another field known as productname in the url  from the function view().Is it possible to do that through 'named' arguments.I went through 'Routing' from cake bakery but it all seems so confusing to me.Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to do some slug routing. Basically, your routes will need to be like this

```
Routing::connect('/portfolio/:slug',
                  array( 'controller'=>'products', 'action'=>'view'),
                  array('pass'=>array('slug'));
```

I'm calling it slug because it's a more familiar term, but you can name it `:product-name` or whatever you want. You'll find more guidance in what you want if you search for "cakephp slug".

Anyway, that route will direct the urls like `portafolio/good-product` to

```
ProductsController->view('good-product')
```

And in the view action, you can translate that product name (slug), to an id. For that create a function in the model, like `slugToId` and call it from the controller

```
public function view($slug) {
    $productID = $this->Producto->slugToId($slug);
}
```

And in the model a simple find will do for that `slugToId` function. Ehm, it's not a requisite for that function to be in the model, but is better practice, specially if you want to do the slug thing in other models, you can reuse the function.

Now, with that you can also use reverse routing, so a call to

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'products',
                      'action'=>'view',
                      'slug'=>'super-awesome-product'))
```

will call the url `cake.com/portfolio/super-awesome-product`.

Read [this tutorial](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/using_url_slugs_in_a_cakephp_app) of slugs, you won't need to do as many changes as suggested there, but it's a good guide.